# Discord Bot doesnt join Voice Chat (Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I do not get any error codes and nothing happens whenever I put the command !join in chat. I searched everywhere it seems like the code should be right. (BTW I do have my bot token in the code)

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
my_secret = os.environ['Token']


client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print ('{0.user} Activated'.format(client))

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
  channel = ctx.author.voice.channel.id
  await channel.connect()



client.run(my_secret)
```

Comment: It seems you're not running the bot, only the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use either [`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#bot) or [`discord.Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Client). Don't use them both. `Bot` has [`event`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.event) and [`command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command).

```py
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


my_secret = os.environ['Token']
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print ('{0.user} Activated'.format(client))

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()


bot.run(my_secret)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need PyNaCl library. Install it with `pip install discord.py[voice]`

```
@Bot.command()
async def join(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel = None):
    if channel == None:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = discord.utils.get(Bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice or not voice.is_connected():
        await channel.connect()
    elif voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    await ctx.send(f'Bot has joined')
```